# Javascript: how to show a popup with <div> content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I would like a popup to appear as soon as my page has finished loading. The content of the popup is html given by the content of a div tag. Here's my code:

```
<div style='display:none; width:500px; height:400px; padding:5px; top:0px; left:400px;' id='popup'>
<div style='float:right'><a id='cchiudi'>Chiudi</a></div>
<br style='clear:both' /><br/>
<center>Per i nuovi clienti offriamo 4h di facchnaggio <strong>GRATUITE</strong>
<BR/><br/>
<a href='http://www.ambientaservizi.it/contact'>
<img src='<?php echo $img_popup; ?>'/>
</a>
<br/><br/>
Per ricevere maggiori informazioni o per prenotare il servizio <br/>cliccare <a href='http://www.ambientaservizi.it/contact'>QUI</a> o cliccare sulla immagine.
</center>
```

```
<script>
function popUP(){

//jQuery("#popup").show();
var w = 500;
var h = 400;
//scroll = 'yes';   
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var popupHeight = jQuery("#popup").height();
var popupWidth = jQuery("#popup").width();
//centering
jQuery("#popup").css({
    "top": "", 
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2,
});

jQuery("#cchiudi").click(function(){
    jQuery("#popup").hide();
});
window.open(jQuery("#popup").html(), "Avviso", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no, height=500,width=400,top="+TopPosition+",left="+LeftPosition);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
popUP();
});
```

It seems simple but I don't know what I am missing because nothing appears. Can you help?

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: yes, no error is signaled

Comment: Have you loaded jquery library ??

Comment: yes, the other things with jQuery work fine so I suppose it is correctly loaded

Comment: And in this fiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/955qdymb/? And why are you complicating yourself by creating the popup with jQuery. When you can simply create that popup with only HTML?

Comment: that fiddle does not work and I don't know how to create a popup with html...

Comment: that fiddle does not work because the content is 404 not found...why?

Comment: Hmmm....it seems that you already have that popup. And you have display none on it. If you simply want it to be showed when page loads, remove the that. Or simply, in your document ready function, put this jQuery('#popup').show();

Comment: If I set `display:block;` in that div it will appear on the bottom of the page as a sort of footer while I want it to be loaded and showed as a popup...

Comment: Well, that's because you didn't styled the popup. Use CSS for that. And also, you should avoid using inline style.

Comment: I don't know what you mean because instead I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105665/discussion-between-ionut-and-lory-lory).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for 
**https://jsfiddle.net/2qmc5xoa/**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("button").on('click', function() {
      showPopup();
  });

  $("#maskLayout").on('click', function() {
    hidePopup();
  });

  $("#popup").on('click', function() {
    hidePopup();
  });

  function hidePopup() {

    $("#popup").hide();
    $("#maskLayout").hide();
  }

  function showPopup() {

    $("#popup").show();
    $("#maskLayout").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Not exactly but it will help me next time. thank you :)